# Howto craft an ActiveRecord join query that only returns Groups where UserGroups.has_left = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, inner-join

A user has_many groups thought GroupsUser. 
We set `@groups_user.has_left = true` when he leaves a group. Because of that, it's not possible to get the groups a user is a member of by doing **@user.groups**.
So I started on crafting a join query, but I haven't grocked it yet.

How can I craft my query so that @user.active_groups only returns those where the groups_users join table has_left equals false?

**app/models/user.rb**

```
 43   # Groups
 44   has_many :groups_users, dependent: :destroy
 45   has_many :groups, -> { distinct }, through: :groups_users
 46   scope :active_groups, ->{ joins(:groups_users)
                                .merge(GroupsUser.active_members) }
```

**app/models/groups_user.rb**

```
 37   scope :active_members, -> { where(has_left: false) }
```

Comment: So, whats the problem you have now? Didn't using `merge` worked?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't quoted `#{self.id}`.
This worked:

```
 48   def my_groups
 49     Group.joins(:groups_users)
           .where("user_id = '#{self.id}'")
           .where("has_left = false")
 50   end
```